# How to use Program.cs file in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

In the latest version of .Net the Startup class and Program class are merged together and the using and other statements are simplified and removed from Program.cs. I am really confused about how to use it all in one file.
Please help me to migrate all services to the program.cs file.

**Startup.cs file :**

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot configRoot;
    private AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();
        Configuration = configuration;

        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        configRoot = builder.Build();

        AppSettings = new AppSettings();
        Configuration.Bind(AppSettings);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddController();

        services.AddDbContext(Configuration, configRoot);

        services.AddIdentityService(Configuration);

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddScopedServices();

        services.AddTransientServices();

        services.AddSwaggerOpenAPI();

        services.AddMailSetting(Configuration);

        services.AddServiceLayer();

        services.AddVersion();

        services.AddHealthCheck(AppSettings, Configuration);

        services.AddFeatureManagement();
    }



    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(options =>
             options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowAnyMethod());

        app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();

        log.AddSerilog();

        //app.ConfigureHealthCheck();


        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.ConfigureSwagger();
        app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
            ResultStatusCodes =
            {
                [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable,
            },
        }).UseHealthChecksUI(setup =>
          {
              setup.ApiPath = "/healthcheck";
              setup.UIPath = "/healthcheck-ui";
              //setup.AddCustomStylesheet("Customization/custom.css");
          });


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**Program.cs file :**

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: "In the latest version of .Net the Startup class and Program class are merged together" <-- uuuhh, this isn't exactly true

Comment: You can still keep everything as it is, just change framework to <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> and update all packages

Comment: @Dai Isn't it? Because the Microsoft documentation article [What's new in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0) does mention that: 

**The web app templates: Unifies Startup.cs and Program.cs into a single Program.cs file.**

Comment: Yeah, the TEMPLATE.

Answer (score 1):

The new template get rid of a lot of boilerplate code. Here is the example according to the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model).

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// The production configuration
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

// Configure the application
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

The advantage is that it achieves the same thing in less code. It is more readable, however a migration should be taken manually.

Or maybe someone came up with some smart migration script? I am not aware of any migration or "program-and-startup-class merger" script, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You modify your csproj file

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```